# Updataing a Database with AJAX with Rubaxa Sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, rubaxa-sortable

I have multiple dynamic lists and list items.

I have successfully implemented Rubaxa's sortable to allow the movement of any list item to any list.

I initialise the JS with a foreach loop on $val['name'] ( each of my lists) eg;

```
new Sortable('.$val['name'].', {
            group: "quotes",
    });';
```

I have tried augmenting the JS with additional lines to initiate an ajax post when the dragged item has landed.

I do not require help with serialisation, or data/database, or php.

My question ( being useless with JS is where and how do i trigger the ajax?

I have tried writing a function, creating events and even random methods which I felt may make sense

Comment: Sortable has a number of events you could hook into, depending on how you have things set up, what about adding an `onSort` handler, the example on [this page](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable) shows the syntax for setting up one or more handler functions.

Comment: Please add this as an answer and I will mark up.  Tested and now working. Thank you